# Physical Significance of normalised and non-normalised function?

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

$\dfrac {\sin(x)}{x}= \rm{sinc}(x)$   unnormalized \rm{sinc} function
And for the normalized sinc we have:
$\dfrac {\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}=\rm{sinc}(x)$ normalized \rm{sinc} function

Is there any physical significance in the difference of normalized and non-normalized function?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function describes this in the intro. Regards

Comment: So is it that the only difference is that one is the time scaled version of the other in terms of pi?

Comment: Pretty much, but as the site also states "The normalization causes the definite integral of the function over the real numbers to equal 1 (whereas the same integral of the unnormalized sinc function has a value of π). As a further useful property, all of the zeros of the normalized sinc function are integer values of x. The normalized sinc function is the Fourier transform of the rectangular function with no scaling. This function is fundamental in the concept of reconstructing the original continuous bandlimited signal from uniformly spaced samples of that signal."